After upgrade to 24.04 LTS server my pacemaker/corosync cluster ipaddr2 resource can't clone an ipaddress across several nodes
oot@sghaproxy01:~# crm status
Cluster Summary:

Stack: corosync (Pacemaker is running)
Current DC: sghaproxy02 (version 2.1.6-6fdc9deea29) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Sat Aug 24 10:10:48 2024 on sghaproxy01
Last change:  Sat Aug 24 10:10:32 2024 by root via cibadmin on sghaproxy01
2 nodes configured
12 resource instances configured

Node List:

Online: [ sghaproxy01 sghaproxy02 ]

Full List of Resources:

Clone Set: clone-fence [group-fence]:

Started: [ sghaproxy01 sghaproxy02 ]


Clone Set: clone-cluster [group-cluster]:

Started: [ sghaproxy01 ]
Stopped: [ sghaproxy02 ]



Failed Resource Actions:

cluster_VIP start on sghaproxy02 returned 'error' (iptables failed) at Sat Aug 24 10:10:32 2024 after 68ms

